# No global Kähler potential on a compact Kähler manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I am required to show that there cannot exist a global Kähler potential $u$ on a compact Kähler manifold, say $(M, J, \Omega)$. I know that $M$ is Kähler if and only if $\mathrm{d} \Omega = 0$ and $J$ is a complex structure, and that *locally* it is always possible to write $$\Omega = i \partial \overline{\partial}u.$$ How does compactness obstruct $u$ being global?

Comment: There are not a lot of globally defined functions on a compact complex manifold.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Not a lot of holomorphic ones, but plenty of smooth ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\Omega = i\partial\bar{\partial}u$, then by the $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma, $\Omega = dv$ for some one-form $v$. In fact, as Arctic Char points out in the comments below, we don't even need the $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma: $$\Omega = i\partial\bar{\partial}u = \partial(i\bar{\partial}u) = d(i\bar{\partial}u) = dv$$ where $v = i\bar{\partial}u$. Then

$$\operatorname{Vol}(M) = \frac{1}{n!}\int_M\Omega^n = \frac{1}{n!}\int_M\Omega\wedge\Omega^{n-1} = \frac{1}{n!}\int_Mdv\wedge\Omega^{n-1} = \frac{1}{n!}\int_Md(v\wedge\Omega^{n-1}) = 0$$

by Stokes' Theorem, but this is a contradiction as $\operatorname{Vol}(M) > 0$.

In general, if $\Omega$ is a Kähler form on a compact manifold, or even just a symplectic form, $\Omega$ is not exact; in particular $[\Omega] \in H^2_{\text{dR}}(M)$ is non-zero.

---

Note, if $M$ is non-compact, there are obstructions to the existence of a global Kähler potential. A sufficient condition is that $H^1(M, \mathcal{O}) = 0$ and $[\Omega] \in H^2(M; \mathbb{R})$ is zero. See [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/221615/21564) for more details.

Comment: The $\partial \overline{\partial}$-lemma I know states that $\Omega = i \partial \overline{\partial} u$ locally if and only if $\Omega$ is closed. How do you get from $\Omega$ being closed to globally exact?

Comment: @ArcticChar: That was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, $\Omega = i \partial \bar \partial u= d( i \bar \partial u)$. $\partial \bar\partial $ lemma not needed.

Comment: @ArcticChar: Nice. I will add this in.

Comment: @ArcticChar ah yes of course, I had even written that down myself. Another point then, are we assuming that $M$ has no boundary? The word "compact" is sometimes really ambiguous.

Comment: I think now the norm is that if $M$ has boundary, it would be explicitly stated. @onamoonlessnight

Comment: @onamoonlessnight: The $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma states that for a compact Kahler manifold, a $d$-closed $(p, q)$-form is $\partial\bar{\partial}$-exact if and only if it is $d$-exact. There are stronger versions of the statement, but this is what I initially used. As Arctic Char pointed out, you don't even need this for the proof.

Comment: @onamoonlessnight: Complex manifolds generally don't have boundary.