# Definition of Kahler manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

First, why $d\Omega=0$ equal to local existence of $u$ such that 
$$
h_{\alpha\overline\beta}=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial z_\alpha \partial \overline z_\beta}
$$

Second, why the whole metric tensor is defined by a unique function ?

Picture below is from [this](http://moroianu.perso.math.cnrs.fr/tex/kg.pdf).

> [image]

Comment: What is a $2$-form?

Comment: @TedShifrin  Thanks ,I forget the definition of $n-form$, and have edit my question.

Comment: The claim is a bit sloppy: The existence of a Kahler potential is guaranteed only locally, the function $u$ need not exist on the entire manifold. What does the author mean by a "unique function" I do not know: It neither exists in general, nor it is unique if it exists. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877004/no-global-k%C3%A4hler-potential-on-a-compact-k%C3%A4hler-manifold

Comment: Also, consider reading Griffiths and Harris or Ballmann's book on K\"ahler manifolds, you can find proof of local existence of K\"ahler potential there (say, Th. 4.17 in Ballmann's book).